# Serverless PHP slim framework POST does not get posted data

Tags: php, post, slim, serverless, bref

I have been exploring serverless php for and I opted on using slim framework because I find it easier to just plugin modules as I go and that what I am building is just landing pages with a few forms.
So I have made the landing pages on slim framework and had it working on traditional servers like micro instances but when I migrated it on serverless php specifically using [bref](https://github.com/mnapoli/bref) but the post method does not seem to work anymore.

I consume the API I made using slim + bref serverless via AJAX. I passed the `contentType : application/json`, with a `POST` method but still not working.

I have used the following methods:

1. `$request->getParsedBody()` -> this works fine on a non-serverless framework. But on serverless php bref it went "internal server error"
2. `$_POST` -> works fine locally and traditional servers but on cloudwatch and var_dumping it is empty array.
3. `$request->getParams()` (not working no method of that is existing but I saw it here in Stackoverflow)

The work around I found was to have it on GET method but I actually want to use POST method because I'd like to use it on passwords.

Anyone who has experienced the same?

Thanks

Comment: What does your `bref` routing configuration look like?

Comment: the `src\bref.php`
`<?php declare(strict_types=1);

include __DIR__.'/public/index.php';`
for a lot more formatting please refer [here:](https://gist.github.com/karenirenecano/b038ae328448c8cbbb81f48fd99e8faa)

Comment: I refer to the routing configuration set for the API Gateway in `template.yaml`

Comment: I am using `mnapoli/bref: "~0.2.27"` it only has `serverless.yml` and my config is like [this](https://gist.github.com/karenirenecano/c7bc27ffad1994509f7f3bbea180c7b5)

Comment: I had initially thought that you were using `bref` as-is. I see that you are using serverless framework and an adapter from `bref`. That is neat! I find it curious that the runtime is `nodejs`. Do you set the `content-type` header in your request? The [implementation seems to only set the parsedBody for requests with the header](https://github.com/mnapoli/bref/blob/0.2.27/src/Bridge/Psr7/RequestFactory.php#L60).

Comment: I did! okay so I will just update the question because I just figured it out, I was using jquery AJAX call. I did use `contenType :application/json'` but it is not working BUT when I did not use ajax and just simply submit the form, the posted data appeared on cloudwatch and got dumped. I guess for some unkown reason it does not work on AJAX(I did try it on postman too,but no luck). I even tried the `file_get_contents("php://input")` to get posted json but still not working. Will just stick to page reloading. (thank you for the link contentType!!)
Thanks again!

Comment: Bref `0.2.x` is quite old (read: very outdated) now that we have layers support in Lambda. We can actually run your PHP site in a PHP-FPM environment and without using a JS shim / adapter (meaning it's easier, feels more native, and is faster). Have a look at https://bref.sh/docs/installation.html for a bit more info about the _current_ tooling (hint, we may move back to `serverless` very soon). Also have a look at https://bref.sh/docs/community for a link to the Slack team where you can post questions directly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just update the question because I just figured it out, I was using jquery AJAX call. I did use contenType :application/json' but it is not working BUT when I did not use ajax and just simply submit the form, the posted data appeared on cloudwatch and got dumped. I guess for some unkown reason it does not work on AJAX(I did try it on postman too,but no luck). I even tried the file_get_contents("php://input") to get posted json but still not working. Will just stick to page reloading.Thanks again!